# Ошибка при установки mediasoup

Tags: c++, node.js, makefile

На Windows 10 запускаю команду

```
npm install mediasoup@3 --save
```

и выдает ошибку

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Savva\project\node_modules\mediasoup
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node npm-scripts.js postinstall
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "postinstall"
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: node npm-scripts.js worker:build
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "worker:build"
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: make -C worker
npm ERR! make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Savva/project/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'
npm ERR! # Updated pip and setuptools are needed for meson.
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Savva/project/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, dirname C:/Users/Savva/project/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/Makefile, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:7: pipe: No error
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:56: pipe: No error
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:93: pipe: No error
npm ERR! ���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:98: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! ���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:98: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! ���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:101: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! "[" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
npm ERR! ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
npm ERR! Makefile:46: pipe: Bad file descriptor
npm ERR! process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, # Updated pip and setuptools are needed for meson., ...) failed.
npm ERR! make (e=2): �� ������� ����� ��������� ����.
npm ERR! make: *** [Makefile:94: meson-ninja] Error 2

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Savva\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-04T08_42_30_694Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Пробовали обновить `pip` и `setuptools`?)

Comment: Все последней версии